# How to make images in a table dynamically fit the size of the browser?

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

I have a table which could contain 1 to 12 images depending on user input. If there is one image then it'll show up in the table nicely. However, if there are 12 images, it'll stretch vertically downwards until I need to scroll down to view the rest of the images.

Is there a way to dynamically resize the images such that no scrolling is required and everything fits into the table?

What it looks like with

5 images:

[image]

12 images:

[image]

This is the current table I have and I use a JavaScript to fill in the images:

```
<table id="first">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li><img id="firstL1"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL2"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL3"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL4"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL5"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL6"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL7"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL8"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL9"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL10"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL11"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL12"></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td><ul></ul></td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li><img id="firstR1"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR2"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR3"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR4"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR5"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR6"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR7"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR8"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR9"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR10"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR11"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR12"></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set percentage widths on the images themselves. An image with `width:100%` will expand to fit the parent table cell, even if that table cell is dynamically resized based on viewport size and the size of other table cells.

[See a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5avjaw72/) with this example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480" style="width:100%"></td>
        <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/240" style="width:100%"></td>
        <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480" style="width:100%"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i tried styling the width and height with percentages but it still stretches down

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question :) Could you draw a rough sketch of how you'd like 12 images to appear? Are you wanting extra columns to spread horizontally?

Comment: basically if there are 12 images, is there a way to squeeze them all into the table such that it'll look like the one with 5 images instead of spreading vertically all the way down?

Comment: can you try for img{ max-width:100%; width:100%;}

Comment: still stretches down.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use `css media query` to resize image on each break point 
for example on screen size 500px make img size 100px

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    img {
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```